# How can i translate this Play 2.4 json stream example to Play 2.5

Tags: playframework, akka-stream

In Play 2.4 I could write:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.extras.iteratees._
val jsonStream: Enumerator[JsObject] =
        enumerator &>
        Encoding.decode() &>
        Enumeratee.grouped(JsonIteratees.jsSimpleObject)
```

To go from a Array[Byte] stream to a JsObject stream.
However now in 2.5 I want to do the exact same thing but using akka-stream but cant find any info for akka-stream on how to do what the above code does?

How does the above code know where to split a stream into each Json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using the [`play-iteratees-extras`](https://github.com/jroper/play-iteratees-extras) library which is, as the name suggests, iteratee-specific. You can do something pretty similar on Play 2.5.6 and above (using Akka Streams 2.4.9) with:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.http.scaladsl.common.EntityStreamingSupport
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

val byteSource = Source.single(ByteString.fromString("""[{"hello": "world"}]"""))

val jsonFraming = EntityStreamingSupport.json(Int.MAX_VALUE)

val jsonStream: Source[JsObject, akka.NotUsed] = byteSource
  .via(jsonFraming.framingDecoder)
  .map(bytes => Json.parse(bytes.toArray).as[JsObject])
```

That currently will only parse a stream of JSON objects from an array. If you want more complete stream parsing support, have a look at [akka-streams-json](https://github.com/knutwalker/akka-stream-json).